# Opening maps from iOS today extension while screen is locked

Tags: ios, widget, mkmapitem

I have a today extension that opens a map via a call of MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems. It works fine if the phone is not locked, but if the today extension is opened from the lock screen, the call doesn't do anything. I would expect the same to happen if you do an "open URL", namely, the screen "Touch ID or Enter Passcode" appears, and once you unlocked the phone, it continues with opening the URL.

Is there any way to achieve the openURL behaviour when opening maps with MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems?

Thanks,
Markus